# JVM. Qual a diferença entre Metaspace e permgen?

Tags: java, jvm

Qual a diferença entre Metaspace e permgen?

Estou há um tempo tentando entender, poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A principal diferença entre as duas é que o Metaspace incrementa seu
>   tamanho de acordo com o uso enquanto a permgen tem tamanho fixo. É
>   possível definir um tamanho máximo para o Metaspace, mas não é possível
>   fazer com que a Permgen auto-incremente seu tamanho.

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131165/what-is-the-difference-between-permgen-and-metaspace

Comment: Gostei da ideia de limitar o tamanho da metaspace

Comment: Mas e ai, respondeu sua dúvida?